# What is the $P( |X-10| > 2)$ of a normal distribution when the mean is 10, and the standard deviation is 6?

Tags: probability, statistics

I couldn't figure out this question: 
What is the $P( |X-10| > 2)$ of a normal distribution when the mean is 10, and the standard deviation is 6?

Comment: We want the probability of being more than $\frac{2}{6}$ "standard deviation units" away from the mean. This is $2\Pr(Z\gt \frac{2}{6})$, where $Z$ is standard normal. tables, or equivalent software. The table will probably give $\Pr(Z\le\frac{2}{6})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(|X-10| > 2)=P(X>12)+P(X<8)=\int_{12}^\infty\cal{N}(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^8\cal{N}(x)dx$$ where $\cal{N}$ is the Gaussian density.

Comment: for the second term are you sure it's $P(X<8)$ not $P(2<X<8)$?

Comment: @user133466 take $X=-10$, then $|-10-10|=20>2$. Assume $\cal{N}$ is discrete, if $2<X<8$ then you dont account for $P(X=10)$ although $-10$ satisfies $P(|X-10|>2)$